# Add image to Crystal Report using return path from database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I have Crystal Report. I need to add logo image to that report by using path return by the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This thread might be old but it can help someone.

1) If the path will be static (means everytime it is not going to be changed based on some condition), then simply drag and oled object on to the report and in the format object option of the same (oled object), specify the path of the image.

2) You can also assign the path to a parameter value if you need to change the value from database.
Assign the path of database to parameter and that parameter will bind path for object.